Unity c# level-up system starts from 2 instead of 1
I'm trying to implement an exponential level-up system based on Runescape's. It seems to be working just as intended, but there is one issue: Whenever I start the game, it starts off level 2 instead of 1, while the required XP is 83, which is the required XP for level 2. So it's correct with requiring 83 XP, but it shouldn't start off Level 2.
Here's my code:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class LevelUpSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int currentLevel;

    public int XP = 0;
    public int reqXP = 83;

    public TextMeshProUGUI levelGUI;
    public TextMeshProUGUI reqGUI;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        levelGUI.text = currentLevel.ToString();
        reqGUI.text = reqXP.ToString();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            GainXP(10);
        }
        // We use "while" instead of "if" in case the player levels up multiple times.
        while (XP >= reqXP)
        {
            LevelUp();
        }
    }

    void GainXP(int amount)
    {
        XP += amount;
        Debug.Log($"Gained {amount} XP. Total XP: {XP}");

        // Check if the XP exceeds the requirement and level up if needed
        while (XP >= reqXP)
        {
            LevelUp();
        }
    }

    public void LevelUp()
    {
        currentLevel++;
        XP -= reqXP; // Reset XP, maintaining overflow
        Debug.Log($"Level Up! New Level: {currentLevel}");

        int firstPass = 0;

        //This is the formula that calculates exponential increase and level up cycles
        for (int levelCycle = 1; levelCycle < currentLevel; levelCycle++)
        {
            firstPass += (int)Math.Floor(levelCycle + (300f * Math.Pow(2f, levelCycle / 7f)));
            Debug.Log(levelCycle);
        }
        reqXP = firstPass / 4;
        
        Debug.Log($"Required XP for next level: {reqXP}");

    }

}

This is how the screen looks (including the debug log)
So far I have tried things like setting the current level at 1 at the start, but it seems to ignore that and just calculates everything within the formula.

Nevermind guys, I solved the issue! It had to do with putting "<=" instead of "<" in the levelCycle.
The script was also changed a lot in the meantime, so it could've contributed to that as well.

Private Void Start()
{
currentLevel = -1;
}
